# Getting stock API data with datetime function, instead of hard code the date

Tags: python, api, datetime

I am trying to get the stock data by using datetime function instead of hard code the date. However, it shows KeyError. Can anyone help?  Thanks!

---

Stock data:

```
'Time Series (Daily)': {'2022-09-30': {'1. open': '266.1450', '2........}
```

---

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

yesterday_close = stock_data['Time Series (Daily)'][yesterday]['4. close']
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    yesterday_close = stock_data['Time Series (Daily)'][yesterday]['4. close']
KeyError: datetime.date(2022, 9, 30)
```

Comment: the error is coming from yesterday being a datetime value instead of a string which is what the dictionary needs to look up the value. you can use https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime to format the datetime to the string that you need for the dict object.

Comment: To debug this, add `print(stock_data['Time Series (Daily)'])`. Or better yet, create a new variable `time_series = stock_data['Time Series (Daily)']` and then `print(time_series)` to see what the valid keys are.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your `datetime.date` object into a string. you can use `.strftime()` for that like this:

```
datetime.date(2022, 9, 30).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Appreciated it, thank you!

Comment: If it works now, please consider accepting this answer to mark the question as solved